# Chrome https connection Not secure - Nginx https server

Tags: nginx, https, ssl-certificate

I have Windows10 host with GUIless ubuntu installed on VirtualBox guest appliance.
I have dedicated home network static IP address for the Ubuntu (198.162.0.110).
On this VBox-ubuntu I have set up nginx proxy server that enables HTTPS connection to a development HTTP Rails server. I use ssh(putty, vscode-ssh, winscp, and other tools) connection to connect my host(win10) to the guest(Ubuntu)in order to utilize a development environment on Windows.

I managed set up Nginx proxy server that enables to connect via HTTPS(I need this to develop and test secure cookies etc.).

Now I am able to connect to the server application like this: https://192.168.0.110 "successfully", but I get the following wanrning:

[image]

I go `Proceed to 192.168.0.110 (unsafe)` and the application appears and work. But now I have to implement social network sign-in (Facebook) and this `Not secure` appears to be a problem.
Facebook demands secure connection:

[image]

Here is my Nginx configuration:

```
 server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        listen 80;
        server_name 192.168.0.110 localhost 127.0.0.1;
        root /home/csrhub/git/csrhub-frontend/public/rails;
        index index.html;
        location / {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8016/;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr; 
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_set_header Port 443;
                proxy_ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/certs/homerouter/homerouter.crt;
                proxy_read_timeout 80s;
        }
        location /api/v2/ {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8014;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_redirect http:// https://;
        }

        ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_ciphers         AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:RC4-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:RC4-MD5;
        ssl_certificate      /etc/nginx/ssl/certs/homerouter/homerouter.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key  /etc/nginx/ssl/certs/homerouter/homerouter.key;
        ssl_session_cache   shared:SSL:10m;
        ssl_session_timeout 10m;
}
```

This is how i generated the certificate: `openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout homerouter.key -out homerouter.crt -config homerouter.conf`

This is the configuration file **homerouter.conf** used when generating the certificate.

```
[req]
default_bits       = 2048
default_keyfile    = localhost.key
distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name
req_extensions     = req_ext
x509_extensions    = v3_ca

[req_distinguished_name]
countryName                 = Country Name (2 letter code)
countryName_default         = US
stateOrProvinceName         = State or Province Name (full name)
stateOrProvinceName_default = New York
localityName                = Locality Name (eg, city)
localityName_default        = Rochester
organizationName            = Organization Name (eg, company)
organizationName_default    = localhost
organizationalUnitName      = organizationalunit
organizationalUnitName_default = Development
commonName                  = Common Name (e.g. server FQDN or YOUR name)
commonName_default          = localhost
commonName_max              = 64

[req_ext]
subjectAltName = @alt_names

[v3_ca]
subjectAltName = @alt_names

[alt_names]
DNS.1   = localhost
DNS.2   = 127.0.0.1
DNS.3   = 192.168.0.110
DNS.4   = 192.168.43.60
```

Obviously I am missing something or at least I do something not the right way.
Please help me to make this connection secure. At the end this is my home local network - everything is trusted here.

Answer (score 0):

Ohh I found the problem:

First I had to add the commonName as hostname(i will choose `homerouter` as a commonName for  local network address `192.168.0.1` where the nginx is situated) on my windows(host machine) here is how: https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/edit-host-file-windows-10/ .

Then, in my **homerouter.conf** I changed the some fields like this:

```
........
default_keyfile    = homerouter.key
........
commonName                  = homerouter
commonName_default          = homerouter 
commonName_max              = 64

[req_ext]
subjectAltName = @alt_names

[v3_ca]
subjectAltName = @alt_names

[alt_names]
DNS.1   = localhost
DNS.2   = 127.0.0.1
DNS.3   = 192.168.0.110
DNS.4   = 192.168.43.60
DNS.5   = homerouter
```

Then I ran the following command:

`certutil -d sql:$HOME/ssl/nssdb -A -t "P,," -n "homerouter" -i homerouter.crt`

I didnt have the corresponding database so I had to create a new one. How? See [here](https://www.dogtagpki.org/wiki/NSS_Database).
And of course added the newly generated certificate to Chorme.

And all worked as a charm!